# Python project: Create a program that keeps track of the items that a wizard can carry

Tags: python

`show` doesn't work and it won't show any of my items

In the first file of my code I have the following content:

items.py:

```
list(inventory_list):
inventory = ["a wooden staff", "a wizard hat", "a cloak of invisibility",

"some elven bread", "an unknown potion", "a scroll of uncursing",

"a scroll of invisibility", "a crossbow", "a wizard's cloak"]
item = inventory.pop()
item = inventory.pop(1)
item = inventory.pop(2)
item = inventory.pop(3)
item = inventory.pop(4)
item = invnetory.pop(5)
item = inventory.pop(6)
item = inventory.pop(7)
item = inventory.pop(8)
```

In my other file which which is the main.py files looks like this.

```
import random
import items as i
inventory_list = 0

def list(inventory_list):
    inventory = ["a wooden staff", "a wizard hat", "a cloak of invisibility",

    "some elven bread", "an unknown potion", "a scroll of uncursing",

    "a scroll of invisibility", "a crossbow", "a wizard's cloak"]
    item = inventory.pop()
    item = inventory.pop(1)
    item = inventory.pop(2)
    item = inventory.pop(3)
    item = inventory.pop(4)



def display_menu(inventory_list):
    random.shuffle(inventory_list)
    print("The Wizard Inventory Program")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("show - Show all items")
    print("grab - Grab an item")
    print("edit - Edit an item")
    print("drop - Drop an item")
    print("exit - Exit program")

def show(inventory_list):
    i = 1
    for item in inventory_list:
        print(str(i) + ". " + item)
        i += 1
    print()

def grab(inventory_list):
    item = input("Name: ")
    inventory_list.append(item)
    print(item + " was added.\n")

def drop(inventory_list):
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    if number < 1 or number > len(inventory_list):
        print("Invalid item number.\n")
    else:
        number = inventory_list.pop(number-1)
        print(item + " was deleted.\n")

def edit(inventory_list):
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    if number < 1 or number > len(inventory_list):
        print ("Invalid item number.\n")
    else:
        number = inventory_list.pop(input())
        print( item + "was edited to.\n")

def main():
    inventory_list = ["a wooden staff", "a wizard hat", "a cloak of invisibility",

    "some elven bread", "an unknown potion", "a scroll of uncursing",

    "a scroll of invisibility", "a crossbow", "a wizard's cloak"]
    display_menu(inventory_list)
    while True:
        command = input("Command: ")
        if command.lower() == "show":
            list(inventory_list)
        elif command.lower() == "grab":
            grab(inventory_list)
        elif command.lower() == "drop":
            drop(inventory_list)
        elif command.lower() == "exit":
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid command. Please try again.\n")
    print("Bye!")

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Another question is do I need to have separate files or can I put it all in one?

Comment: SO isn't an assignment completion service.

Comment: You are asking about this `show` method/function but I don't see the code for this anywhere. What are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more along the lines of what you're looking for. Also, I will help you out because I can see from your code a few places you are struggling, but please review the rules regarding posting questions to SO, because as mentioned this does not fit the profile. And also examine what I'm doing differently and try to grasp why.

```
import random
inventory_list = []

def display_menu(inventory_list):
    random.shuffle(inventory_list)
    print("The Wizard Inventory Program")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("show - Show all items")
    print("grab - Grab an item")
    print("edit - Edit an item")
    print("drop - Drop an item")
    print("exit - Exit program")

def invalid_number(num):
    try:
        x = inventory_list[num]
        return False
    except IndexError:
        return True

def show(inventory_list):
    for i, item in enumerate(inventory_list):
        print("{}. {}".format(i, item))
    print()

def grab(inventory_list):
    item = input("Name: ")
    inventory_list.append(item)
    print(item + " was added.\n")

def drop(inventory_list):
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    if invalid_number(number):
        print("Invalid item number.\n")
    else:
        orig_inp = inventory_list[number]
        del inventory_list[number]
        print("'{}' was deleted.\n".format(orig_inp))

def edit(inventory_list):
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    if invalid_number(number):
        print ("Invalid item number.\n")
    else:
        orig_inp = inventory_list[number]
        new_inp = input("What would you like to call '{}' instead? ".format(orig_inp))
        inventory_list[number] = new_inp
        print("'{}' was edited to '{}'.\n".format(orig_inp, new_inp))

def main():
    inventory_list = ["a wooden staff", "a wizard hat", "a cloak of invisibility",

    "some elven bread", "an unknown potion", "a scroll of uncursing",

    "a scroll of invisibility", "a crossbow", "a wizard's cloak"]
    display_menu(inventory_list)
    while True:
        command = input("Command: ").lower()
        if command == "show":
            show(inventory_list)
        elif command == "grab":
            grab(inventory_list)
        elif command == "drop":
            drop(inventory_list)
        elif command == "edit":
            edit(inventory_list)
        elif command == "exit":
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid command. Please try again.\n")
    print("Bye!")

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```